# What is the ViewID of the Internal Web Browser and how to find viewID of any view?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

What is the ViewID of the Internal Web Browser. I saw this question a couple of times but no answer anywhere! I know there is a plugin spy tool but i could never use it successfully! Can you tell me about the tool also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: org.eclipse.ui.browser.view

Comment: had got it here: http://sandipchitale.blogspot.in/2008/08/info-eclipse-view-and-perspective-ids.html